# Colors aren't showing in the "Shop By Color" area

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I'm using color swatches for version 1.9.1

I got everything working up until the point that it changes the color of the product by clicking one of the images, so that's fine. However, when I go to say a category, let's say "Decorations" and I notice that some of the colors aren't present.

By this I mean that on the Left Hand Side under Colors some of them will actually be a picture of the color and others will be the name e.g. "Green" instead of the green swatches image.

I added all images under the main product (not the configurable)

Comment: Have you tried flushing the Swatch Images Cache (and all other cache)? And check what is inside the `/media/wysiwyg/swatches/` folder, do you see the `green.png` (NOTE: all lowercase) image file? This could also be related to browser cache, so check with another browser too.

Comment: @ForMat thanks for the reply. No, they were not present in that directory. It's weird that magento accepted the upload for 3/6 of those image files that were uploaded (all at the same time). Unless this is something that is expected to be done manually. Thanks for the solution, it's now fixed.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it is fixed now! I have added my comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image files for swatches are stored in the `/media/wysiwyg/swatches/` folder. Check and see if the `green.png` (NOTE: all lowercase) image file and other missing colors are present.

If the images are not there, try to upload them again using the "Insert Image" function of the WYSIWYG editor in the Admin Panel or upload images manually using FTP or SSH.